# given javaClass 'class com.google.gson.JsonObject' is mapped to ValueType, expected ManagedType

Tags: java, javers

Hi I am getting below error when i am using Javers.compare(oldDoc, newDoc) . 
Its working fine if inside document no any data with ArrayList

Error :- given javaClass 'class com.google.gson.JsonObject' is mapped to ValueType, expected ManagedType

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javers MANAGED\_CLASS\_MAPPING\_ERROR with ArrayList<JSONObject>.compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366494/javers-managed-class-mapping-error-with-arraylistjsonobject-compare)